# Question about using book down in R-do I need to load packages on each page? Help with basic understanding!

Tags: r, rstudio, rmarkdown, bookdown

Please forgive the v basic question. I have recently started using R bookdown, to try write papers. I've read the cookbook and book down guide. I use rmardown, and understand that, but I don't understand how bookdown 'knows' what to put together.
As instructed by the helpsheets, I have several chapters:

- an index
- 01-introduction (mainly free text)
- 02 methods (mainly tables)
- 03 results (outputs, graphs, tables)
- 04 concolusion (free text).

Normally in rmarkdown, every new file I open, I have a 'r set up' chunk where I set the initial global decisions for the doc (echo=TRUE for example). I also install and load all packages I need for that document.
Do I still need to do this in bookdown? Or do I do it only once in the index chapter? I just don't quite understand what to put in index and what not to put in the other chapters.

Also, every time I save, it creates a 'book' folder, and 'book down files'. I presume I just don't touch these?

Lastly: If I create a graph in chapter 3 can I put it in chapter 2? Or does it render in order of chapters, and is the better way to have a separate file for all the code for my graphs?

Thanks so much

Comment: Welcome to TeX S.E. I didn't use `rmarkdown`, neither `bookdown`; I'm not even sure if this is the right place to ask (is TeX involved?), but usually you have a master file that links to all your files. Put your settings there and you probably won't need to add them on each file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect R chunks, the important point to understand this is that bookdown default rendering approach is “**Merge and Knit**” (M-K), but it is possible to make a  “Knit and Merge” (K-M), so what you need about R chunks depend on this. With default M-K is like compiling a single file of Rmarkdown, so what you do in a R chunk in "Introduction" will be taken into account in the R chunks of "Results". All the code run in a single R session. With the alternative approach, R code of each chapter is executed independently.

With respect to LaTeX, no matter if you use the M-K or the K-M approach, at the end there are a markdown merged version that is exported to LaTeX format, so that   the compiler will always work with a single document, and therefore you must supply all the LaTeX settings just once, in the YAML header in `index.Rmd`  (or in a separate YAML file named `_output.yml`) and nothing more. Note also that for the same reason, a LaTeX command in .Rmd  file (e.g. `\Large` or `\parskip5em`) could apply not only the file that you edit, but also all the following files. (this could cause some surprises, you cannot detect this in previews of single files).

Finally, the  `_book` directory is for the outputs, i.e., where you get the book in PDF or all the HTML book structure, while   _bookdown_files is a cache folder for files required during compilation.